# Gitlab: Not able to save the Gitlab admin settings after upgrading the gitlab from 16.7.5 to 16.8.2

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-omnibus

I have upgraded the gitlab version from 16.7.5 to 16.8.2.

After upgradig the gitlab I am trying to change the gitlab admin setting as I am Administrator of my gitlab instance.But facing the below issue:

**Application settings update failed.**

**The form contains the following errors:**

- Help page documentation base url is blocked: execution expired
- Diagramsnet url is blocked: execution expired
- Public runner releases url is blocked: execution expired

  Please find the below image for reference:

[image]

I also tried to change the settings by using root user, but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve my issue.

The solution is to run psql commands and directly change the boolean values for two of the properties. This is done via the gitlab-psql command.

**gitlab-psql**

**update application_settings set diagramsnet_enabled=false;**

**update application_settings set update_runner_versions_enabled=false;**

**\q**

**sudo gitlab-ctl restart**

Next delete the help page url manually from the application.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue here. Upgraded from 16.0.8 to 16.8.2. Even having the same issue from a fresh installation of 16.8.2.

Comment: This could only be a comment but isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @ryan I have provided the answer below.
Try this you will be able to resolve your issue.
Thanks